Serilog; Keeping logs seperate, Two different .net framework DLLS Want each dll in it;s own logfile
I've built two different COM Dlls each having its own Serilog output to a file.  Standalone they work fine. These DLLs perform separate tasks and are not related nor dependent on each other.
In DLL A I create a Log File A_datetimestamp.log.
In DLL B I create a Log file B_datetimestamp.log.
I use these dlls in VBA solutions for my customers.  Recently I had to use both for the same customer.
When I create instance of DLL A my log starts as usual.
When I create instance of DLL B my log start as usual, but after that point any logging done by DLL A ends up in the file for DLL B.  Also all Logging for DLL B is in that same log file.
I really want to keep the logs separate at all times.  Is there something I should be doing to ensure output for DLL A is Log A and output for DLL B is Log B?
In my "modules" I have an Initialize method that calls the following to  start a Log.
    private static void StartLogger(string logFQN, string logLevel = "Verbose", bool isStationLog = true)
    {
      var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();
      switch (logLevel.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper())
      {
        case "V":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
          break;
        case "D":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
          break;
        case "I":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
          break;
        case "W":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
          break;
        case "E":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
          break;
        case "F":
          levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Fatal;
          break;
      }
      if (!isStationLog) //Deal with Global log by controlling filesize
      {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
          .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
          .WriteTo.File(logFQN,
          shared: true,
          fileSizeLimitBytes: 524288000, //5Meg
          outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\t{EnvironmentUserName}\t[{Level:u4}]\t{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
          .CreateLogger();
      }
      else
      {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
          .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
          .WriteTo.File(logFQN,
          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
          outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}\t{EnvironmentUserName}\t[{Level:u4}]\t{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
          .CreateLogger();
      }
    }


This has very little with COM. Both dlls are loaded in-process, after that it's all a matter of how you've written the code.
